# Mover el widget principal que depende del widget preview

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-widget

He diseñado un botón widget en una página de configuración preview de perfil de usuario. En esta página puedo configurar el botón con caracteristicas de texto, color, fuente y posición. Todos los cambios se guardan en el preview menos el de posición. Este es el código del botón en el preview:

```
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label>Position</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="position_wp" id="position_wp" onchange="preview_wp()">
        <option value="Right"
            @if($company->position_btn_wp == 'Right')
                selected="selected"
            @endif>Right</option>
        <option value="Center"
            @if($company->position_btn_wp == 'Center')
                selected="selected"
            @endif>Center</option>
        <option value="Left"
            @if($company->position_btn_wp == 'Left')
                selected="selected"
            @endif>Left</option>
```

El botón en la página principal no cambia de posición como debería hacerlo de acuerdo a la configuración del preview. Este es el código del botón en la página principal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function () {
    var baseUrl = window.location.host;
    var protocol = "https://";
    if(baseUrl !== "sch.dev.com" && baseUrl !== "scheduly.zontly.com" && baseUrl !== "scheduly.com" && baseUrl !== "www.scheduly.com") {
      baseUrl = "scheduly.com"
    }
    if(baseUrl === "sch.dev.com"){
       protocol = "http://";
    }
    var wgt = document.createElement("script");
    wgt.type = "text/javascript";
    wgt.async = true;
    wgt.id = "widgetJs";
    wgt.src = protocol + baseUrl +"/themes/widget/js/widget.js?clientId=356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wgt, s);
})();</script>.
```